# Read out .csv and hand results to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am learning some coding, and I am stuck with an error I can't explain. Basically I want to read out a .csv file with birth statistics from the US to figure out the most popular name in the time recorded.

My code looks like this:

```
# 0:Id, 1: Name, 2: Year, 3: Gender, 4: State, 5: Count

names = {}       # initialise dict names
maximum = 0      # store for maximum
l = []


with open("Filepath", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        l = line.strip().split(",")
        try: 
            name = l[1]
            if name in names:
                names[name] = int(names[name]) + int(l(5))
            else:
                names[name] = int(l(5))
        except:
            continue

        print(names)    
        max(names)


def max(values):
    for i in values:
        if names[i] > maximum:
            names[i] = maximum
        else:
            continue

        return(maximum)

print(maximum)
```

It seems like the dictionary does not take any values at all since the print command does not return anything. Where did I go wrong (incidentally, the filepath is correct, it takes a while to get the result since the .csv is quite big. So my assumption is that I somehow made a mistake writing into the dictionary, but I was staring at the code for a while now and I don't see it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I think there were a few flow issues: I called a function before defining it... is that an issue or is python okay with that?

Also I think I used max as a name for a variable, but there is a built-in function with the same name, that might cause an issue I guess?! Same with value

This is my final code:

```
names = {}       # initialise dict names
l = []

def maxval(val):
    maxname = max(val.items(), key=lambda x : x[1])
    return maxname


with open("filepath", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        l = line.strip().split(",")
        name = l[1]
        try: 
            names[name] = names.get(name, 0) + int(l[5])
        except:
            continue

    #print(str(l))
    #print(names)    

print(maxval(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions to improve your code:

```
names = {}       # initialise dict names
maximum = 0      # store for maximum

with open("Filepath", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        l = line.strip().split(",")
        names[name] = names.get(name, 0) + l[5]

maximum = [(v,k) for k,v in names]
maximum.sort(reversed=True)
print(maximum[0])
```

You will want to look into Python dictionaries and learn about `get`. It helps you accomplish the objective of making your `names` dictionary in less lines of codes (more Pythonic).

Also, you used `def` to generate a function but you never called that function. That is why it's not printing.

I propose the shorted code above. Ask if you have questions!

Comment: Ah right I used the get function in another lecture but was not using it since it didn't appear yet in the lecture I'm currently doing.... I'll try that

With the function call of max - I thought functions are called by their names and the parameters I want to hand over which would be right above the function definition? `max(names)`Is this not call the function with the dictionary names as parameter?

Comment: Also, the list unpacking (?) in the ```maximum = [(v,k) for k,v in names]
maximum.sort(reversed=True)
print(maximum[0])```code causes an error.

Thanks for your help so far though, the get function is indeed very useful!